# Как подключить yandex appmetrica в ReactNative?

Tags: typescript, react-native, yandex-appmetrica

Делаю по документации:
https://appmetrica.yandex.ru/docs/mobile-sdk-dg/plugins/react-native/react-native-plugin.html

```
import AppMetrica from 'react-native-appmetrica';
```

=>

```
TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'react-native-appmetrica'.
```

Использую:

```
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-native": "0.70.2",
```

Answer (score 0):

[Перевод с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54163816/13349770)

Вот что вы должны сделать. После успешной настройки библиотеки в вашем проекте на любой платформе (`VsCode` или `Atom`). Повторно запустите проект из командной строки `react-native run-android`. После этого перейдите к своему проекту в `Android Studio`. Затем откройте `build.gradle` и снова синхронизируйте свой `gradle`. Затем, чтобы убедиться, проверьте `MainApplication` в `Android Studio`, чтобы убедиться, что файл (например, `import com.whatever.foo`) импортирован правильно, если все выглядит хорошо, всё готово

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 
Открыл Android Studio и пытался собрать получаю ошибки в kotiln коде модуля appmetrica: Unresolved reference: lowercase.
Подключал разные плагины:
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

Не помогает